# Inserting initial data JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to load initial data in my database ?

I am using JPA and am using the Drop and Create strategy, this way every time i want to test my application the database is first cleared and i would have to recreate everything all over again.

I know in other languages (Php -> Doctrine datafixtures, C# -> Context) it is possible to load initial data after the persistention of the classes.

However i tried searching for such feature in java and i can't find a good way to do this. I have found several topics across stackoverflow about this but none of them seem to have a good answer. I am using a java desktop application (not spring)

Comment: You want to load the data so you can test the application or is this data used by the app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is totally possible. Your JPA implementation should have some mechanism to register a script for the drop and/or create phase. Here are some examples:

- EclipseLink: see eclipselink.create-dll-jdbc-file-name http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL
- Hibernate: even simpler, just put a file named import.sql on the classpath and select the right strategy (e.g. create-drop) (http://christopherlakey.com/articles/import-sql.html)
- Persistence: source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm

  ```
  <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/createDDL_ddlGeneration.sql" />
  ```

In case you only need this for testing, you could also prefill the database in a setup method. But obviously that would not be a JPA mechanism anymore.

Comment: For Hibernate, I would rather suggest another way using property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" which allows to specify more than one SQL script file, see http://blog.netapsys.fr/hibernate-et-la-personnalisation-des-fichiers-dimports/ (in French)